# recreate the slide technique of photojojo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for some guidance on how I can recreated a this feature. what it does is when you click DO NOT PULL, scroll to an anchor button with a inimation. You can see it action here. http://photojojo.com/store/awesomeness/iphone-dot-pano-lens/

can anyone help me understand how that happens? The source code tells me nothing..

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways - you can either make a complex animation in flash and export as a gif, or play the flash.

Then on your JS side of things you will set a timeout for say 2 seconds when that happens 
`$('html').scrollTop(600);` // really that can be any number just a set position to scroll

so the full execution would be something like

```
$('btn').click(function(){
  $('#wrapper').append("<img src='myanimation.gif' id='ani'>");
  setTimeout(scrollDown,2000);
});

function scrollDown(){
  $('html').scrollTop(600);
  $('#ani').remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Drew, the 'btn', would be the trigger class right?

Comment: yeah it would trigger the animation to be added and play. and what that does is add the GIF to the page and the timer would start assuming your animation is 2 seconds long, after 2 seconds it will scroll the page. You'll want to add a second or so after the animation ends for it to stay still so it doesn't loop.

Answer (score 3):

Referencing Drew's answer, this particular example isn't done as Flash or a GIF.

All they've done it layered six PNG images on top of each other and hidden them. Then once user interaction occurs they show then hide each image in the sequence. With the last image visible they then perform the page scroll. Once the animation is complete the last image in the sequence is hidden again. Rinse repeat for each click.

Drew's method for scrolling the page will work fine. You could also use the .animate() method if you wanted easing or other more complex control.

Comment: Side note: Looks like they are also animating one or more of the PNG images slightly so it appears smoother (the bounce etc).